How does Bayesian updating rule imply representation by Subjective Expected Utility?
In economics, I frequently heard these claims:

Bayesian updating rule implies representation by Subjective Expected Utility (SEU)
Dynamic consistency implies SEU

However, I don't know the precise arguments and theorems. Can you give me some hints?

My Try:
Let:
$S$ be a finite state space
$X$ be a set of outcomes
$\mathcal{F}$ be the set of acts $f: S \to X$
$\succeq$ be a preference relation over $\mathcal{F}$
$\mathcal{P}(S)$ be the power set of $S$
$E \in \mathcal{P}(S)$ be an event
$\succeq_E$ be the conditional preference given event $E$

[Bayesian Updating Rule] For any event $E$ and prior probability $p$
on $S$, the posterior probability $p_E$ is given by: $$p_E(s) =
> \frac{p(s)\mathbf{1}_E(s)}{\sum_{s'\in S} p(s')\mathbf{1}_E(s')} =
> \frac{p(s)}{p(E)} \text{ for } s \in E$$ where $\mathbf{1}_E$ is the
indicator function of event $E$.

[SEU Representation]
If preferences $\succeq$ and conditional preferences $\{\succeq_E\}_{E\in\mathcal{P}(S)}$ satisfy:

Dynamic Consistency: For acts $f,g \in \mathcal{F}$ and event $E$:
$$f \succeq_E g \text{ iff } fEh \succeq gEh \text{ for all } h \in \mathcal{F}$$


Consequentialism: For acts $f,g \in \mathcal{F}$ and event $E$:
$$f(s) = g(s) \text{ for all } s \in E \implies f \sim_E g$$

And some standard axioms like continuity and weak-ordering.
Then there exists an SEU representation for the preference (Guess).
